# In wxPython, how can I use sizers to left- and right-justify statictext beneath a slider?

Tags: python, layout, wxpython, wxwidgets, sizer

I'm trying to make a GUI like so:

[image: picture of my intended layout]

The big square is a wxGrid, the small ones are wxButtons, and they all act fine.  The drawing at left is intended to be a wxSlider, with text labels "slow" and "fast" beneath each end of the slider.

So I lay out a bunch of BoxSizers, like this:

[image: hierarchy of BoxSizers]

From outside in:

- Blue is vertical, and contains a wxGrid and the green BoxSizer
- Green is horizontal, and contains the orange BoxSizer and two buttons
- Orange is vertical, and contains a wxSlider and the purple BoxSizer
- Purple is horizontal, and contains two StaticTexts, with the words "slow" and "fast"

But the closest I can get it to render is this.
Notice especially how the slider is tiny, and the slow and fast labels (intended to mark the ends of the slider!) are a mess.
[image: my crappy outcome]

I've messed with alignments and expands, I've read a bunch of posts from other people complaining about BoxSliders, and I've gotten nowhere.  I thought for sure I had it when I read about wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE, but that didn't do anything.  I even rebuilt my window with wxGlade, and got the same thing, especially with the static text laid out far left.

The one thing I haven't done is specified the size of anything in pixels.  It doesn't seem like any layout should require that, because who knows what size screen I'll be running on or what a reasonable number of pixels is.  And if I've understood proportions correctly in sizers, I don't have to specify sizes in pixels.

But I'm out of ideas, and I haven't even found a good example, just similar veins of frustration.
How do I make my slider take up the full width of the orange boxsizer, and how do I get the slow and fast text to label the ends of the slider?

What I'm running, stripped to the layout essentials (and it's got the slider and labels problem):

```
import wx
import wx.grid

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title="MyUnhappyLayout")

blue_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

grid = wx.grid.Grid(frame)

blue_sizer.Add(grid, 6, wx.EXPAND, 8)

green_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
blue_sizer.Add(green_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

button1 = wx.Button(frame)
button2 = wx.Button(frame)

slider = wx.Slider(frame, name="Speed", value=1, minValue=1, maxValue=100)

purple_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
label_slow = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Slow")
label_fast = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Fast")
purple_sizer.Add(label_slow, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
purple_sizer.Add(label_fast, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

orange_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
green_sizer.Add(orange_sizer, 2)
orange_sizer.Add(slider)

orange_sizer.Add(purple_sizer, wx.EXPAND)
green_sizer.Add(button1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
green_sizer.Add(button2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

frame.SetSizerAndFit(blue_sizer)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: can you post the code on how do you create the slider and how do you add it to the sizer? Also what is wxPython version and OS you are trying?

Comment: @Igor, yep - posted code a moment ago.  I'm running Win10, Python 3.9.2, and wxPython 4.1.1

Comment: did you try `orange_sizer.Add(slider, 1, wx.EXPAND)`

Comment: @Igor - when I change a couple lines to: `orange_sizer.Add(slider, 1, wx.EXPAND); orange_sizer.Add(purple_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)`, that at least got my slider to be the full width of the orange sizer.  Didn't work without both changes, and still doesn't fix the text.  And since i dunno how to put a \n in this box, I gave Python an imaginary semicolon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "built-in" option for showing min and max labels for a slider: use `wxSL_MIN_MAX_LABELS` when creating it (unless you are using wxWidgets older than 2.9.1).

Otherwise, for your specific sizer layout (it might be easier to review if you create each sizer just before using it):

```
purple_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
purple_sizer.Add(label_slow)
purple_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
purple_sizer.Add(label_fast)

orange_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
# when adding to a sizer, the second argument would be proportion;
# use SizerFlags to avoid mistakenly skipping an argument
orange_sizer.Add(slider, wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
orange_sizer.Add(purple_sizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand())

green_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
green_sizer.Add(orange_sizer, wx.SizerFlags(1)) # no need for proportion=2, 1 should do
green_sizer.Add(button1) # you probably meant to enlarge the slider, not the buttons
green_sizer.Add(button2)

blue_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
blue_sizer.Add(grid, wx.SizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(8)) # no need for proportion=6, 1 should do
blue_sizer.Add(green_sizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
```

Comment: @RolfofSaxony what do you mean by "this"? Surely should you have read the entire answer you'd have seen that the first phrase suggests the available labels, while the rest of it is about the OP's exact code.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and I apologise unreservedly. You're making use of the `AddStretchSpacer` which I didn't spot. I don't recall when it was added but as you can see, I'm still using the old workaround `(-1,-1)` to achieve the same result. Accept my upvote.

Comment: I looked at wxSL_MIN_MAX_LABELS; I didn't see a way to use it to apply text labels, just the min and max values I'd assigned to the slider.

Comment: The code worked!  And I think I understand what it's doing, between adding the AddStretchSpacer and changing the arguments to wx.SizerFlags() -based.  The only thing which didn't work on the first try was the Border(8); something threw an exception about wanting a additional directions argument to Borders.  Adding wx.ALL to the arguments made it go.

Answer (score 0):

As @VZ has pointed out to me, the old `Align` within a boxsizer in it's orientation, never worked but now throws an error in newer iterations of wxWidgets.
Now, the `old` way to achieve the same result, is to insert `dummy` entries into the `sizer` and ask for them to be expanded.

For the `new` way see the answer from @catalin.

Some of the changes to your code are cosmetic to help me understand what is what, by explicit rather than implicit with the defaults for widgets.

```
import wx
import wx.grid

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title="MyUnhappyLayout")

blue_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

grid = wx.grid.Grid(frame)

blue_sizer.Add(grid, 6, wx.EXPAND, 8)

green_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
blue_sizer.Add(green_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

button1 = wx.Button(frame)
button2 = wx.Button(frame)

slider = wx.Slider(frame, name="Speed", value=1, minValue=1, maxValue=100)

purple_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
label_slow = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Slow")
label_fast = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Fast")
purple_sizer.Add(label_slow, 0, 0, 0)
purple_sizer.Add((-1,-1), 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
purple_sizer.Add(label_fast, 0, 0, 0)

orange_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
orange_sizer.Add(slider, 0, wx.EXPAND)
orange_sizer.Add(purple_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

green_sizer.Add(orange_sizer, 2, 0, 0)
green_sizer.Add(button1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
green_sizer.Add(button2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

frame.SetSizerAndFit(blue_sizer)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Note:
This is the dummy entry:
`purple_sizer.Add((-1,-1), 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)`

Comment: Using alignment in 1D boxsizer orientation **never** worked, it's just that it was silently ignored in previous wx versions, but gives an assert failure now. Hopefully this will help with the confusion about it.

Comment: @VZ. Good to know, Cheers!